# Есть ли возможность редактировать мою Яндекс Карту другому пользователю?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Возможно ли передать "мою" Яндекс Карту, созданную под моей учётной записью, которую имею возможность редактировать только я, другому пользователю, чтобы он тоже мог добавлять на карту новые точки, убирать старые, добавлять линии и объекты на карту и т.д., т.е. иметь полный доступ к редактированию карты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент в [Конструкторе](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) не реализована совместная работа с картами. Можно лишь [экспортировать](https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/markers_3.html) карты в файл и передавать другому пользователю для импорта на его аккаунте.